# how to make correct fn args when create fn using macro

Tags: clojure, macros

My Clojure app needs some handlers to do business, those handlers will preform some common parameters check, so I use a macro to do this like below:

```
(defmacro defapihandler [handler-name params & body]
  `(defn ~handler-name ~params
     (let [keyed-params# (map keyword '~params)
           checked-ret# (check-param (zipmap keyed-params# ~params))]
       (if (:is-ok checked-ret#)
         (do ~@body)
         (-> (response {:code 10000
                        :msg  (format " %s are missing !!!" (:missed-params checked-ret#))})
             (status 400))))))
```

Then I can use  above macro like this:

```
(defapihandler create-user [username password birthday]
  ;; todo 
)
```

Everything is fine this way.

As you can see, the params of generated fn is constructed directly from args of the marco, exception raised when params of generated fn can't constructed directly.

Take a example:

The `params` of the macro `defapihandler` now became like this:

```
[{:key :username :checker [not-nil?]} {:key :password :checkers [is-secure?]} ...]
```

In the macro, I want to build the param of the generated fn dynamicly like this:

```
(defmacro defapihandler [handler-name params & body]
  `(defn ~handler-name [passed-param#]
     (let [param-keys# (vec (map (comp symbol name :key)
                                ~params))
           {:keys param-keys#} passed-param#]
       ;; some check
       (do ~@body))))


(defapihandler create-user [{:key :username :checkers []}]
  (println username))
```

The structure of `passed-param` looks like this: `{:username "foo" :password "bar"}`

Now I want to construct the variables used in `body` block in `let` block, Then following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

`macroexpand` `create-user` got this:

```
(defn create-user [passed-param__10243__auto__]
  (let [param-keys__10244__auto__ (vec
                                    (map
                                      (comp symbol name :key)
                                      [{:key :username,
                                        :checkers []}]))
        {:keys param-keys__10244__auto__} passed-param__10243__auto__]
    (do (println username))))
```

I suspect this exception is related to dynamic var used in let destructuring form, if my suspect is right, then how to construct variables used in `body` block ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pull the clause that builds your params-key vector out of the generated code.

So:

```
(defmacro defapihandler [handler-name params & body]
  (let [param-keys (map (comp symbol name :key) params)]
    `(defn ~handler-name [passed-param#]
       (let [{:keys [~@param-keys]} passed-param#]
         ;; some check
         (do ~@body)))))
```

Or if you don't need `passed-param#`:

```
(defmacro defapihandler [handler-name params & body]
  (let [param-keys (map (comp symbol name :key) params)]
    `(defn ~handler-name [{:keys [~@param-keys]}]
       ;; some check
       (do ~@body))))
```

Comment: your code did work, but I still am confused why should use `[]` literally, my code will try to resolve `param-keys#` as a `Symbol` not a `ISeq` as the exception said

Comment: Symbols in an argument vector, or on the left side of a `let` clause are not resolved. For example, `(let [x 'a, x 2] x)`. In this, `x` will be first set to the symbol `a`, and then `x` will be set to `2`. You won't find that `x` is `a` and `a` is `2`.